# Do we need the [error] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

Does tagging a question [error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) really add much information to it?

Or should we dispose the [error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) tag?

Comment: I agree that it is a nice distinction, but that distinction should anyway be clear by reading the question text. I see no use for the `error` tag when searching for questions to ansewr, or searching for solutions to problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have blacklisted [error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error).

Answer (score 7):

That seems to be the very definition of a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

No one is going to be an expert in all errors.

No one is going to follow that tag.

It cannot, by itself, describe the question.

Most damning of all, it is useless without some other tag to say what app there is an error.

I say it should be burninated.

Comment: Burninate! That was the word I was looking for.